# jQuery hide/show does not work, unlike the JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<strong class="comment" id="comment[6]">Show comments</strong> 
<div id="comments[6]">HERE GO COMMENTS</div>
```

And my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".comment").click(
            function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("comment", "comments");
            //document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            $('#' + id).hide();
            } );
        });
```

HTML code is generated with PHP, so there are a lot of numered divs and each click show/hide the corresponding div. But problem is that as far as Javascript is concered (commented line) everything works, but when I try to use jQuery nothing happens. Where is the problem?

Comment: Disregarding the horrible implications of using `"#"+id` code, why are you doing `$(this).attr("id")` over `this.id` ?

Comment: I'd guess that jQuery is trying to do some selector magic with the [] in your ids. Does it work if you take them out? I.e. Comments6 rather than comments[6]

Comment: like @RobH said you are better not coding around the problem if possible. Renaming the id's with the number at the end or some other character separating them like an "_" or "-" would be readable and prevent you needing to add extra code and complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because [square brackets have special meaning within a jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). If the actual id contains square brackets you need to escape them with backslashes:

```
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
                    .replace("comment", "comments")
                    .replace(/(\[|])/g,"\\$1");
```

Amazing demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B3Hx9/

Comment: Simply jawdropping. +1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Well yes, invalid as a CSS selector, but it is a [valid id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) - got to love the consistency. jQuery already allows selectors that aren't part of the CSS spec at all though, so... (Still, if it were my code I wouldn't use the square brackets, I'd use an underscore or something. Also having parallel ids with "comment" and "comments" is just going to lead to hard to find typo-based bugs.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **escape the [ ] using \\**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".comment").click(
            function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id","comments");
            //document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            $('#' + id).hide();
            } );
        });
```

Comment: This line: `var id = $(this).attr("id","comments");` _sets_ the id attribute of the clicked item and sets the `id` variable to the jQuery object containing the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are throwing off your id selector as they are special characters when used in this case to allow you to do things like specify additional attributes.

While you can escape them you would be better to not use them at all e.g. have your number appended to the id with an underscore or some other character. Adding regex to get around the problem is not optimal as you are adding complexity when changing how the id itself is structured would make the whole thing simpler.

**[Example changed to use id_number format](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dp8s/)**

```
<strong class="comment" id="comment_6">Show comments</strong> 
<div id="comments_6">HERE GO COMMENTS</div>
```